# Deleting Orphaned AWS ENI + SG? `currently in use` and `has a dependent object`?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

`aws ec2 delete-network-interface --network-interface-id eni-xxx`

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValue) when calling the DeleteNetworkInterface operation: Network interface 'eni-xxx' is currently in use.

`aws ec2 delete-security-group --group-id "sg-yyy"`

> An error occurred (DependencyViolation) when calling the DeleteSecurityGroup operation: resource sg-yyy has a dependent object

If I do:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances > instances.json
aws ec2 describe-nat-gateways > nat-gateways.json
aws ec2 describe-network-acls > network-acls.json
aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces > network-interfaces.json
aws ec2 describe-security-groups > security-groups.json
```

Then this just shows the single self entry in `network-interfaces.json`:

```sh
grep eni-xxx *.json
```

This shows the self entry in `security-groups.json` and one reference from `eni-xxx` in `network-interfaces.json`:

```sh
grep sg-yyy *.json
```

The following:

```sh
aws ec2 describe-security-group-references --group-id sg-yyy
```

produces an empty result:

```
{
    "SecurityGroupReferenceSet": []
}
```

No EC2 instance is using the ENI. Why can't I delete either the ENI or the SG? I believe both of these are orphaned.

I'm guessing the SG's dependent object is the ENI? But the ENI doesn't seem like it's in use. No EC2 instance references it. What can I do to remove these?

Comment: Lambda uses ENIs, load balancers, RDS, Global Accelerator, and EFS all use ENIs... there are probably others... what does `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces` reveal?  There should be a hint in there.

Comment: fyi, this is in context of creating an EKS cluter with eksctl, and trying to delete it, and getting this error. I'm not using Lambdas, RDS and I haven't heard of the other two.

Comment: Thanks. What does `aws ec2 describe-network-interfaces` show, in the `description` field (or perhaps elsewhere in the response)?

Comment: `"Description": "ELB zzz",`. I was able to delete the elb `aws elb delete-load-balancer --load-balancer-name "zzz"` but I'm still not able to delete the eni or the sg.

Comment: That was it. After waiting 15 minutes or so, the ENI seemed to automatically delete, and I was able to manually delete the SG without error. Thanks!

Comment: @clay Thanks!! You gave me the clue to the same issue. Once I terminated the ELB, with extreme prejudice, I was able to take out the subnets and finally the cluster via Cloudfront console, since ekctl couldn't detect the cluster.